# devise sign_in_and_redirect never seems to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, devise, omniauth

I would like it, if after a user logs in, that it automatically redirect to their previous location, but this never seems to happen, it always redirects back to the root location.  From reading the docs on devise for this it seems this functionality is supposed to just work.  Am I using it somehow wrongly and/or how can I force it to store the location and redirect regardless?

http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Controllers/Helpers#stored_location_for-instance_method

```
authentication = UserToken.find_by_provider_and_uid(omniauth['provider'], omniauth['uid'])

if authentication
  flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => omniauth['provider']
  sign_in_and_redirect(:user, authentication.user)
else
```

Comment: i just realized i'm not getting the default functionality because i'm not use the authorize_user! callback which stores the location... so how can I create the location manually?

Comment: how did u solve that? I am following https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview to integrate facebook login for a rails 3.2.5 app with Devise. The sign_in_and_redirect method is not working :(

Comment: I had the same issue, just did a manual sign_in and a separate redirect, check the source code of sign_in_and_redirect

    sign_in @user
    redirect_to root_path

Answer (score 4):

Scroll to the bottom of [this Google group page](http://groups.google.com/group/plataformatec-devise/tree/browse_frm/month/2010-06?_done=/group/plataformatec-devise/browse_frm/month/2010-06%3F&) and check out the overridden 'stored_location_for' devise method. I have an adapted version of it in my application_controller that looks like this:

```
  def stored_location_for(resource)
    if current_user && params[:redirect_to]
      flash[:notice] = "Congratulations, you're signed up!"
      return params[:redirect_to]
    end
    super( resource ) 
  end
```

That should let you create the location manually by passing in a 'redirect_to' param.